# Ruby redirect output to file

Tags: ruby, io-redirection

How can I redirect the output of this `puts` method to a file?

```
File.open('links.txt').readlines.each do |li|
  puts li if (li['PersonNight'])
end
```

I tried some solutions, but none of them works.

Comment: "None of them works" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Does the behavior you are observing differ from the behavior you are expecting? What is the expected behavior? What is the behavior you are observing? How do they differ?

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". If you tried something, show us what and ask a specific question about that. Without it it appears you didn't really try. Routing output to a file is in the IO and File documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You either can write to a file explicitly (open file and write to it)

```
file = File.open('target.file', 'w') do |file|
  File.foreach('links.txt') do |li|
    file.puts(li) if li['PersonNight']
  end
end
```

Or redirect from outside your script, using regular unix machinery

```
ruby my_script.rb > target.file
```

Comment: [`File.open`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/File.html#method-c-open) with a block or at least `ensure` :)

Comment: @mudasobwa: yeah, I didn't want to use their entire code, that's why. :) But you're right, we should show good practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts) on the [`IO`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html) object for the file you want to write to:

```
File.open('outputfile.txt', 'at') do |out|
  File.open('links.txt').readlines.each do |li|
    out.puts li if (li['PersonNight'])
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can redirect the output of [`Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) by assigning an output file to `$stdout`:

```
old_stdout, $stdout = $stdout, File.open('outputfile.txt', 'at')

File.open('links.txt').readlines.each do |li|
  puts li if (li['PersonNight'])
end

f, $stdout = $stdout, old_stdout
f.close
```

But this is a really bad idea. You redirect `puts` for all code in the system.

Comment: I had to do the second once, and it is useful in the case of needing all output to be directed somewhere, but using `>` at the command-line is less intrusive.